# auth0 page redirect not working in ASP.MVC

Tags: auth0

I have my auth0 'Allowed Callback URL's' set to http://myapp/LoginCallback.ashx,http://myapp/

But I never hit LoginCallback.ashx.  When I set the callbacks to just http://myapp/LoginCallback.ashx I get an error from auth0 saying:

Callback URL mismatch. http://myapp/ is not in the list of authorized callback URLs: http://myapp/, http://myapp/LoginCallback.ashx;

If i set the callback to http://myapp/ it returns it with an auth code but obviously does set anything up because it hasn't hit the ASHX page.  I followed the ASP.Net tutorial step 2  to the letter but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated

EDIT: 'Allowed Callback URL's' should have been set to http://myapp/ and Lock's callbackUrl set to http://myapp/LoginCallback.ashx

Comment: Quick questions for clarification-- have you made sure you're pointing to the app that you've cleared those callbacks for? If you have multiple apps this can sometimes trip users up.

Also, is there whitespace between the two URLs in your allowed callback URLs field on the dashboard? If you copy/pasted it from your dashboard here, there is no whitespace and that might be interfering and treating both URLs as one?

Comment: @KassandraPerch Thank mate but it is as describe below, hadn't placed my callback url in the lock config.  As an aside, if you're logged in to auth0 the tutorial places your urls in the code snippets but is a little less verbose if your not.  Maybe a little more narrative might help the newbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the list of allowed callback URLs, but which callback URL you're specifying when logging in. Make sure to use `http://myapp/LoginCallback.ashx` as the specified `redirect_uri` (if calling the /authorize endpoint directly) or `callbackURL` if you're using Lock/auth0.js.